# python-3.5.2: command not found

Tags: software-installation, python

I followed the procedure mentioned in the below link to install python-3.5.2.

[Using tar file](http://tecadmin.net/install-python-3-4-on-ubuntu-and-linuxmint/)

However after doing `sudo make altinstall`  if I type `python-3.5.2 -V`
I get `python-3.5.2: command not found`. How should launch python-3.5.2.

How to use python-3.5.2 using IDLE ?

Upon the suggestions in comments:

```
$ python-3.5
python-3.5: command not found
$ python3 -V
Python 3.4.2
```

Again after this I went with another suggestion by Benny.

Now I have Python 3.5.2.
But I don't see IDLE with Python 3.5.2.

> $ python3 -V
>
> Python 3.5.2

How to get IDLE for 3.5.2 ?

`

Comment: Try `python-3.5`, AFAIK python is installed as python, pythonX, pythonX.Y?

Comment: Try `python3` ?

Comment: Why installing python? It's already there

Comment: Please limit your post to a single question. If you've got something else to ask, please open another question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the required python-3.5 version.
Try to download it from https://www.python.org/downloads/.
Choose your target system and launch the installer.
The setup wizard should launch. You should just click "Next" for every option in the setup wizard.